# Firefox addon remove not clearing local storage

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In chrome when you install a extension it clears the local storage associated with that extension. This doesn't seem to be the case for Firefox.

The only possible solution I can find is

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listening_for_load_and_unload

To listen for the 'install' event and clear it manually.

The problem Im having with this is that at the time main.js gets this event, my page-workers are already unloaded. I need to clear local storage which main.js cannot. So I need to emit to the page-worker so it can do so but the page-worker is already unloaded at this time.

Comment: That's interesting. Did you have a question?

Comment: Is this the best solution? Is there a way for it to actually clear the storage on uninstall like Chrome rather then having to intercept a uninstall event and do it manually.

Comment: You're right, firefox keeps it in case user reinstalls the extension. Peronsally for my add-ons, when user uninstalls it, i delete all traces of it. Because that's how I expect software uninstalls to work for me. So just delete everything on uninstall of your addon :)

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to include my main issue now that I know how to intercept the uninstall:

The problem Im having with this is that at the time main.js gets this event, my page-workers are already unloaded. I need to clear local storage which main.js cannot. So I need to emit to the page-worker so it can do so but the page-worker is already unloaded at this time.

Comment: @yoyo Isn't there a `onDetach` or some kind of event on the `page-workers`, so you can delete the local storage on that event?

Comment: I believe that would be called even when the extension is closed, simply closing the browser where I only want to do the action on uninstall.

Comment: "I need to clear local storage which main.js cannot." Do you mean an HTML5 page's `localStorage` object or the SDK's [storage module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-storage)?

Comment: I mean HTML5's localStorage.

Answer (score 2):

The Firefox add-on SDK doesn't integrate with HTML5 local storage. So one solution is to use message passing and [simple storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-storage) instead, then it should be wiped for you, as expected.

If it isn't, in main.js, you can simply write:

```
const { storage } = require('sdk/simple-storage');
exports.main = function({ loadReason }) {
  if (loadReason==='install') for (var prop in storage) delete storage[prop];
}
```

If you need to use `localStorage`, store an array of affected pages in simple storage, then create a page-worker for each site on install and clear `localStorage` from each new content script.

Comment: Maybe you mean `require("sdk/simple-storage").storage;` here. Anyway, it doesn't work.